# Stored procedure/query two variable comparison

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have created a stored procedure for SQL Server 2014.

There are two parameters: `Name` which is a user name and `Hash` which is password md5 hash. I check in the database if the md5 hashes are equal (first hash is from the program and the second one is already stored in the database).

If I just run a query (not a stored procedure) in the database (or in program using `commandType.Text`) - everything works and the user is being selected, but when I run the exact thing but using stored procedures, the `SqlReader` in C# has no elements returned, which most likely means that the conditions during those variable comparison were not met.

Maybe I am doing something wrong?

I also have about 10 other stored procedures for reading or/and writing to the database, everything works except this one.

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHash
   @Name nvarchar(50),
   @Hash nvarchar(200)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Orders.orderId, Employee.name, Employee.surname
    FROM Orders 
    LEFT JOIN Employee ON Orders.orderId = Employee.id
    WHERE batchName = '@Name' AND productCode = '@Hash'
END
GO
```

Code part:

```
    public Boolean VerifyPassword(string name, string password)
    {
        var paramsList = new List<SqlParameter> { new SqlParameter("@Name", name), new SqlParameter("@Hash", GetMd5Hash(password)) };

        const string ProcedureName = "GetHash";
        var ActiveUser = new DBController().GetFromDatabase(ProcedureName, "Login", "EJL15_DB", paramsList).ToList();
        return ActiveUser.Count > 0;
    }
```

And from Database Controller

```
    private void SetCommandProperties(string procedureName, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> paramsList)
    {
        this.sqlCommand.CommandText = procedureName;
        this.sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        foreach (var curParam in paramsList)
            this.sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(curParam);

        this.sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 15;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to quote the parameters in the stored procedure. Do this instead:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetHash
    @Name nvarchar(50),
    @Hash nvarchar(200)

AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT Orders.orderId, 
           Employee.name, 
           Employee.surname
    FROM Orders 
    LEFT JOIN Employee
        ON Orders.orderId=Employee.id
    WHERE batchName = @Name
    AND productCode = @Hash
END
```

Answer (score 0):

- I just wonder, obviously your @Hash parameter passed to the stored
  procedure is a user's password. But for some reason your WHERE clause
  in the procedure goes like that:

> "WHERE batchName='@Name' AND **productCode='@Hash**'"

Is there a chance your condition is incorrect? I guess it should be something like:  Employee.password = @Hash

- You should not put '' around your variables. Otherwise your comparison is totally wrong.